# Assign values from irregular grid points to standard grid points using interpolation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have (a lot of) data like below

```
y = [1, 3, 4, 5]
```

which corresponds to the grid points

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

On the other hand, I have a standard grid

```
X = [1, 3]
```

What I need is to assign the value of `y` at `x[1] = 2` and `x[3] = 4`, which are not in `X`, to the grid points in `X` using linear interpolation. For example, `y[1] = 3` at `x[1] = 2` will be allocated equally to the grid points `X[0]` = 1 and `X[1] = 3`.

The final result is expected to be

```
Y = [2.5, 10.5]
```

I have to handle millions of `y` and the grid points `x` could be different, so efficiency is important.

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html ?

Comment: Thank you JohanC. I know interp too but could not finger out how to use the function for the purpose. Any details?

Comment: Maybe you could clarify the question a bit with a small drawing?  And maybe also use other variable names, as the difference between `x` and `X` is confusing.